# How to access dynamically created controls(Server side) in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamic, controls

I have created several text boxes dynamically in code behind (c#) that represent a quantity field for a certain type of memory. Each text box is associated with a price attribute and a size attribute. My overall goal is to use Javascript to update(for each textbox multiply the quantity by the price and size attributes then add all together) a "total Size" and "Total Price" field using a command such as onblur or something similar(I am open to different options if there are any). The problem I am having is I am not sure how to access the controls from Javascript being that they are dynamically created.

Here is my code behind. Thanks in Advance I appreciate it.

```
for (int I = 0; I < DataSetCount; I++)
        {
            tbArrMemory[I] = new TextBox();
            lblmemory[I] = new Label();
        }
        while (N < DataSetCount)
        {

            tbArrMemory[N].Height = 20;
            tbArrMemory[N].Width = 20;
            tbArrMemory[N].Text = "0";
            tbArrMemory[N].ID = "tbArray" + N;
            tbArrMemory[N].Attributes.Add("onblur", "checkDimm(" + tbArrMemory[N].ClientID + ");");
            tbArrMemory[N].Attributes.Add("Price", dsMemory.Tables["MemoryConf"].Rows[N]["Price"].ToString());
            tbArrMemory[N].Attributes.Add("GBSize", dsMemory.Tables["MemoryConf"].Rows[N]["GBSize"].ToString());

            lblmemory[N].Width = 600;
            lblmemory[N].Text = dsMemory.Tables["MemoryConf"].Rows[N][dsCol].ToString();
            plhDrives.Controls.Add(lblmemory[N]);
            plhDrives.Controls.Add(tbArrMemory[N]);

            plhDrives.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/></br>"));
            N += 1;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
document.getElementById("id")
```

In your case, you're setting the ids to be

```
"tbArray" + N;
```

so they will be tbarray0, tbarray1, etc... You'll probably want to loop through them.